# JavaFX WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @...'

Tags: java, javafx

I just downloaded JavaFX and set it up, I have done nothing else. I ran the sample code and this was the warning that popped up, although everything compiled. I'm using IntelliJ.

This is in Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is in sample.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

When running, everything compiles, the window pops up, but I get the warning as stated in the title.

I never used JavaFX before so I'm unsure of where to locate this module.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Make sure JavaFX is resolved as *named modules*.

- Non-modular application:

  ```
  java --module-path <path-to-fx> --add-modules <fx-modules> ...
  ```
- Modular application:

  ```
  java --module-path <path> --module <main-module>/<main-class> [args...]
  ```

  Where `<path>` includes your module as well as JavaFX.
- Use JDK distribution which includes JavaFX (see answer below for more information). May still need to use `--add-modules`.

Or, if you decide you're okay with an unsupported configuration, you can simply ignore the warning. As far as I know, nothing currently breaks as of JavaFX 21.

---

## Background

This warning is related to the *Java Platform Module System* (JPMS) introduced in Java 9. If you're not familiar with modules, then I recommend reading [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) for a brief overview.

With JPMS came the module-path, which now exists alongside the class-path. When classes are loaded from the class-path they become a part of the so-called *unnamed module*. Whereas classes on the module-path are contained within modules, and are thus loaded "into" *named modules*. A named module may or may not be *automatic*, depending on if it has a `module-info` descriptor or not, respectively.

---

## The Warning

JavaFX only supports being loaded as *named modules*. In other words, JavaFX only supports being loaded from the module-path, not the class-path. This has been implicitly true since version 9, back when the framework was modularized. But now, as of version 16, a warning is emitted if JavaFX detects it was loaded from the class-path (i.e. is in the *unnamed module*). See [JDK-8256362](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8256362).

---

## Solution

The solution is to make sure JavaFX is loaded from the module-path and resolved as *named modules*. Note JavaFX is made up of seven modules, as can be seen by [its documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/).

How exactly you ensure JavaFX is resolved as named modules may depend on your environment (e.g. non-modular vs modular application, external JavaFX SDK, etc.). The examples below all use the command-line to show how to set the needed arguments. However, if you're using an IDE (e.g. NetBeans, IntelliJ, Eclipse) and/or a build tool (e.g. Maven, Gradle) and are unsure of where to set these arguments, then check out [Getting Started with JavaFX 11+](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Note that both Gradle and Maven have plugins that make it easier to work with JavaFX (i.e. they handle all the configuration for you).

### Non-modular Application

If your code is non-modular then you do not have a `module-info` descriptor. This means adding JavaFX to the module-path is not enough; you also have to force Java to resolve the JavaFX modules. That can be done via the `--add-modules` argument.

For example:

```
java --module-path <path-to-fx> --add-modules javafx.controls ...
```

Notice I only include the `javafx.controls` module in the `--add-modules` argument. This is because it requires the `javafx.base` and `javafx.graphics` modules, which means they will be implicitly pulled in.

If you need other modules then you need to include them in the `--add-modules` argument as well, separated by a comma.

Also, note it's okay, in this case, to have your code and other non-modular dependencies on the class-path. The important part is that JavaFX is loaded from the module-path.

### Modular Application

If your code is modular then you *will* have a `module-info` descriptor. This descriptor will have the necessary `requires` directives. In this case, you no longer need to use `--add-modules`, but you do need to make sure to launch your application as a module via `--module`.

For example:

```java
module app {
  // transitively requires javafx.base and javafx.graphics
  requires javafx.controls;

  // export javafx.application.Application implementation's package
  // to at least javafx.graphics
  exports com.example.app to javafx.graphics;
}
```

```
java --module-path <path> --module app/com.example.app.Main [args...]
```

Note for this you need to not only put JavaFX on the module-path, but also your own module.

### Use a JDK Distribution that Includes JavaFX

Since Java 11, JavaFX is no longer included in the JDK provided by Oracle. But Oracle is not the only vendor for Java based on OpenJDK. There are vendors out there that provide JDK distributions which include JavaFX. At least two of them are:

- [BellSoft Liberica JDK](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/) (make sure to choose the "Full JDK" option).
- [Azul Zulu JDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk-fx) (make sure to choose the "JDK FX" package).

Also note that you can [use `jilnk` to create a Java runtime that includes the JavaFX modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76155054/2189127).

When JavaFX is included in the JDK, it's now part of the run-time image like all the other Java modules (e.g. `java.base`). This means it will automatically be loaded as *named modules* and you no longer have to manually put JavaFX on the module-path.

### Ignore the Warning

As far as I can tell, nothing **currently** breaks if JavaFX is loaded from the class-path (as of version 21). This means another option, at least for now, is to just ignore the warning. Though anything that *does* break because of this configuration is unlikely to be fixed by the JavaFX developers.

However, I recommend putting at least JavaFX on the module-path if you can do so without too much trouble.

Note when JavaFX is loaded from the unnamed module (i.e., class-path), then the main class **cannot** be a subtype of `javafx.application.Application`. You **must** define a separate main class whose main method simply launches the JavaFX application. This is true for JavaFX 9 up to and including at least JavaFX 21.

---

## Deployment

The above mostly helps during *development*. What about deployment? How do you include JavaFX with your application and also have JavaFX loaded from the module-path?

Note this section is only intended to list some options for deployment. It does not give details. There are many existing resources on the internet for more information. See the "Packaging" section of the [JavaFX tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) page for some links.

### Require Clients Have a JRE with JavaFX Installed

This is essentially the same as "Use a JDK Distribution that Includes JavaFX" from earlier. However, instead of the client having a JDK installed they should just have a JRE installed. Note a JDK is just a JRE but with development tools included.

This approach is likely impractical unless you control the client computers.

### Distribute a Self-Contained Application

A self-contained application includes your application code, all library code, and the JRE itself. This means the client doesn't even need to have Java installed.

One way to create a self-contained application is via [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jlink.html) and/or [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) ([user guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A)). Note that `jlink` only works with non-automatic modules, whereas `jpackage` can work with non-modular applications and can also work with a mix of modular and non-modular dependencies (e.g., put JavaFX on the module-path, but have everything else on the class-path). However, unlike `jlink`, the `jpackage` tool does not support cross-platform compilation.

Another option is [GraalVM's native image](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/).

### Executable "fat" JAR File

Historically, Java applications are distributed as an executable JAR file. A so-called "fat", "uber", or "shadowed" JAR file simply has all dependencies embedded with the application in the same JAR file. You can use this approach to include JavaFX with your application transparently. Note this requires the client have an appropriate version of Java installed.

Using this approach is implicitly unsupported. The *JAR File Specification* does not support multiple modules per JAR file, nor does it define any way to specify the module-path. Additionally, executable JARs are typically launched via the `-jar` switch which puts everything on the class-path. All this means that JavaFX will be loaded from the unnamed module. In short, this approach is essentially the "ignore the warning" solution for deployment.

The same stipulation regarding the main class applies here just as in the "Ignore the Warning" section earlier.

Comment: Can you expand on your point (3)? when is that javaFx has gone back into the standard library?

Comment: @MarcoServetto I edited my answer. I now include links to two vendors which provide JDKs that include JavaFX.

Comment: OMG... after literally 4 days of searching how to build a jar from Maven project in IntelliJ, this was the final solution which worked. God bless you @Slaw !

Comment: Could you please also note that in case you want to download JDK distribution that includes OpenJFX like Liberica, at their website they have Standard and Full versions of their JDK. Standard version does not include OpenJFX! It was really confusing to me since I downloaded their source code and noticed that openjfx was present, but it wasn't present after JDK installation.

Comment: @YuriyKirel Note I do mention "_make sure to choose the 'Full JDK' option_" for Liberica and "_make sure to choose the 'JDK FX' package_" for Azul.

Comment: @Slaw Holy lord... tunnel visioning to the max

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but I have a question: it seems to imply that all of the JavaFX modules be present explicitly on the end user's workstation.  I am able to produce a single .JAR file that runs my application correctly; the only issue is the warning message.  I would like to deal with that, but if it means that my end user needs not only my standalone .JAR file but a bunch of JavaFX files as well, that's a pretty big impediment.  Is this the case, or am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to avoid the warning, then I recommend creating a self-contained application via e.g., `jlink` / `jpackage`. If you want to deploy as a single executable fat JAR file, then you just have to ignore the warning. The client probably won't even see the warning unless they launch the application via the terminal.

Comment: currently this gives "java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found" and does not run, not just a warning. and double clicking a runnable .jar does not do anything, because of the same error. the error is from java -jar myapp.jar from console.

Comment: @Goofyseeker311 That's a different problem from this Q&A. But it sounds like you didn't include the native code, or included the native code for a different platform, in your JAR file.

Comment: correction: eclipse did not include the binaries, even if they were used by eclipse during run time successfully. modular version using javafx instructions is broken. all the instructions are broken. evil.

Comment: well I tried loading the platform binary dlls by hand from a self-written loader class, but still the eclipse gui run works and console java -jar myapp.jar and  double-click start does not work, same pipeline not found error.

Comment: @Goofyseeker311 You're putting way too much work into this if you're writing your own "loader class". JavaFX will handle loading the native code, assuming you include it appropriately. All you should have to do is make sure the native code for the platform(s) you are targeting is under the root of the fat JAR file. Unfortunately, I don't know Eclipse very well, so I don't know the exact steps you need to take to make sure the native code is included in your fat executable JAR file. If you need more help, I suggest [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: yeah got it working on the root. this happens when things dont work simply. need to be seeking out solutions to resolve the solution, right?

Comment: never asking any question ever again, makes things only worse.

Comment: How do I define the `<path-to-fx>`, if OpenJFX is provided by Gradle? The JARs are located in a hidden `.gradle/caches` folder. Is there any smart way pointing to that path in IntelliJ?

Comment: @user1438038 If you want to run your JavaFX application in your development environment and you're using Gradle as your build tool, then modify your build script as needed to apply the  [`application`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) and [`org.openjfx.javafxplugin`](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin) plugins, configure both those plugins appropriately (follow links for more information), and finally execute the `run` task. If you want to run the project via IntelliJ, create a run configuration to execute the aforementioned Gradle task.

Comment: @Slaw: I've the `java` and `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` plugin set up, starting my JavaFX client with a run config already. Just trying to get rid of that "classes were loaded from unnamed module" message. I know where to pass VM arguments in my run config, but I struggle pointing to `<path-to-fx>`. Isn't that path *managed* by Gradle dynamically?

Comment: Or does the `application` plugin do some additional magic, that the `java` plugin doesn't?

Comment: @user1438038 The `application` plugin adds the `run` task (follow link in my previous comment for documentation). The `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` plugin will modify the `run` task to put JavaFX on the module-path when your code is non-modular; if your code is modular, then the `run` task already handles placing everything on the module-path. And your IntelliJ run configuration should be executing the _Gradle task_ (i.e., delegate to Gradle).