# How to solve java.lang.IllegalAccessException (JavaFX) on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I try to tidy up the file for my app by creating seperate packages according to the functionality and encounter this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement (in module javafx.fxml) cannot access class application.login.Login (in module eSentral_Desktop_App) because module eSentral_Desktop_App does not export application.login to module javafx.fxml
```

My question is how to fix this and what cause it to happen?
Here are some extra Information:
This is my class hierarchy:
[image]

this is my Main.java code:

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import jfxtras.styles.jmetro.JMetro;
import jfxtras.styles.jmetro.Style;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import java.io.IOException;
import application.login.Users;
import application.listing.Homepage;
public class Main extends Application{
    public static Object currentUser = new Object();
    double x,y = 0;
    private static Stage stg;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        try {
            stg = primaryStage;
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login/LoginUI.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            JMetro jMetro = new JMetro(scene, Style.LIGHT);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void changeScene(String fxml) throws IOException {
        Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml));
        stg.getScene().setRoot(pane);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my LoginUI.fxml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="800.1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.login.Login">
   <top>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="115.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="249.0" layoutX="276.0" layoutY="18.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../resources/ic_eSentral_Logo.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="133.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnRegister" layoutX="248.0" layoutY="63.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseEntered="#MouseEnter" onMouseExited="#MouseExit" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="318.0" style="-fx-background-color: #169fe3;" text="Register a new account" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="311.0" layoutY="24.0" text="Don't have an account yet?" textFill="#1286bc">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </bottom>
   <center>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="487.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="lblSuccess" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="318.0" textFill="#00ff26">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="txtUsername" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="77.0" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="318.0" promptText="Email">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <Label fx:id="lblEmail" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="121.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="318.0" textFill="#ec1e1e">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <PasswordField fx:id="txtPassword" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="145.0" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="318.0" promptText="Password">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </PasswordField>
            <Label fx:id="lblPassword" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="189.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="318.0" textFill="#ec1e1e">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="lblForgot" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="326.0" layoutY="226.0" onMouseClicked="#forgetPassword" onMouseEntered="#MouseEnter" onMouseExited="#MouseExit" text="Forget your password?  " textFill="#1286bc" underline="true">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="lblForgot1" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="380.0" layoutY="35.0" text="Login" textFill="#1286bc">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Button fx:id="btnLogin" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="274.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#login" onMouseEntered="#MouseEnter" onMouseExited="#MouseExit" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="318.0" style="-fx-background-color: #169fe3;" text="Log in" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btnFB" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="380.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseEntered="#MouseEnter" onMouseExited="#MouseExit" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="318.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4766a9;" text="Log in with Facebook" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="63.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/ic_facebook.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Separator layoutX="247.0" layoutY="338.0" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="130.0" />
            <Separator layoutX="434.0" layoutY="338.0" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="130.0" />
            <Label layoutX="392.0" layoutY="337.0" text="OR" textFill="#1286bc">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

This is module-info code:

```
module eSentral_Desktop_App {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires java.net.http;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires com.google.gson;
    requires java.logging;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires org.jfxtras.styles.jmetro;
    
    opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
}
```

Comment: oh alright, will add it immediately

Comment: Study: [java modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Comment: There will be a duplicate somewhere, but I won’t look for now.

Comment: It is working, thank you for your help!

Comment: Great. As you are refactoring, consider moving to the [Maven standard layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), you can than also optionally use the build tool of your choice (maven or gradle), which helps make the project better to share and maintain over time, just a suggestion, not related to your question.

Comment: In module-info, add `opens application.login to javafx.fxml`, linked doc explains why.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your suggestion. I am considering building it on Gradle but don't understand it enough yet to use it. Will get to it later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you to [jewelsea](/questions/tagged/jewelsea), this problem is solve. All I need to do is add

```
opens application.login to javafx.fxml;
```

into module-info.java.

It will look like this:

```
module eSentral_Desktop_App {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires java.net.http;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires com.google.gson;
    requires java.logging;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires org.jfxtras.styles.jmetro;
    
    opens application.login to javafx.fxml;
    opens application to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

There are at least two solutions:

1. Add an `opens application.login to javafx.fxml` directive to your `module-info.java` file. For those of you who are not the OP, replace `application.login` with your own controller's package.
2. Make your code non-modular by deleting the `module-info.java` file. I recommend keeping JavaFX on the module-path in this case. If you don't know how to do that, see [Getting Started with JavaFX 11+](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/). If you don't keep JavaFX on the module-path you'll get [this warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67854139/6395627), as technically JavaFX does not support being placed on the class-path.

---

## IllegalAccessException

This error is related to the *Java Platform Module System* (JPMS) added in Java 9. If you're not familiar with modules, I recommend reading [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) to learn the basics.

One of the goals of JPMS was to add stronger encapsulation to Java. This means:

1. The public<sup>**1**</sup> members of a package in module `A` can only be accessed by code in module `B` if the package is **exported** by module `A` to *at least* module `B`. Exporting a package is done via an `exports` directive inside the module descriptor (the `module-info.java` file).

   Note public members of an *exported* package can also be accessed via [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful).
2. The private<sup>**2**</sup> members of a package in module `A` can only be accessed reflectively by code in module `B` if the package is **opened** by module `A` to *at least* module `B`. Opening a package is done via an `opens` directive in the module descriptor.

### Error Message

The error message takes the form of:

```
class C (in module A) cannot access class D (in module B) because module B does not export P to module A
```

Where class `D` is your class which is in your module `B`. And `P` is the package of class `D`. Note that class `C` is not really important here.

If the error message says, "does not **export**", then the fix is to add:

```java
module B {
    // other directives

    // add this
    exports P to A; // where 'to A' is optional (qualified vs unqualified exports)
}
```

<sup>**Warning:** Make sure to read the "Solution" section below before trying to use a qualified `exports`.</sup>

Whereas if the error message says, "does not **open**", then the fix is to add:

```java
module B {
    // other directives

    // add this
    opens P to A; // where 'to A' is optional (qualified vs unqualified opens)
}
```

Note it's possible the error first talks about not *exporting* a package, only to then complain about not *opening* a package after you add an `exports` directive. It depends on how the code using reflection is implemented.

---

<sup>**1.** This means `public` classes and any `public` members (i.e., methods, fields, etc.) of said `public` class. Note that a `public` .e.,g method declared in a non-public class is not considered a "public member" (in this context, at least).</sup>

<sup>**2.** Anything not covered by "public members", in other words `protected`, package-private, and `private`. Note if you want to invoke a non-public member reflectively, you have to call `setAccessible(true)` (or `trySetAccessible()` and checking the return value).</sup>

---

## Solution

In your case, the error is about a class in the `application.login` package. The examples below are based on that.

Your error says, "does not **export**". That would imply, from what I described above, that you should add an `exports` directive to your module descriptor. This would be fine if, and only if:

- You have no FXML-injected fields, or all those fields are `public`.
- You have no `initialize()` method, or that method is `public`.
- You have no event-handler methods linked from the FXML file, or those methods are all `public`.

If you meet those requirements, then having:

```java
// WARNING: Does not actually work with JavaFX
exports application.login to javafx.fxml; // a qualified exports
```

Would fix the problem. **At least, that would be true if JavaFX didn't [perform its own checks](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.fxml/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/fxml/MethodHelper.java#L58) (for methods) in addition to the normal JPMS checks.** For whatever reason, JavaFX decided that qualified exports are not acceptable when invoking a method via reflection. You would have to use an *unqualified* exports:

```java
exports aplication.login;
```

**However**, it's rare an FXML controller would meet all those requirements listed above. If you had no FXML-injected fields, no `initialize()` method, and no event handler-methods, then why have a controller in the first place? And if you do have any of those, they really should all be `private` as they're all implementation details of the controller. So, the **proper solution** is to add an `opens` directive:

```java
// JavaFX is perfectly fine with qualified opens, just not qualified exports
opens application.login to javafx.fxml;
```

As if the error message said, "does not **open**".

And this is all documented by [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#deploy_as_module):

> #### Deploying an Application as a Module
>
> If `FXMLLoader` is used to load types in a named module, the application must ensure that all types that are referenced in the FXML files, including the controller class and any custom `Node` classes, are reflectively accessible to the `javafx.fxml` module. A type is reflectively accessible if the module `opens` the containing package to at least the `javafx.fxml` module.
>
> For example, if `com.foo.MyController` is in the `foo.app` module, the `module-info.java` might look like this:
>
> ```java
> module foo.app {
>     opens com.foo to javafx.fxml;
> }
> ```
>
> Alternatively, a type is reflectively accessible if the module `exports` the containing package unconditionally.

<sup>- This is also documented by the `@javafx.fxml.FXML` annotation.</sup>

### Alternative Solution

An alternative solution is to make your code non-modular. You would do this by deleting the `module-info.java` file from your project. This may be preferable, particularly if your code *directly* depends on non-modular dependencies.

That said, if you do make your code non-modular, I recommend you keep JavaFX on the module-path. If you don't, then you'll the warning described in the following Q&A:

- [JavaFX WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @...'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67854139/6395627).

And if you don't know how to make sure JavaFX is on the module-path, see [Getting Started with JavaFX 11+](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).