# How to run Spring Boot JavaFX Maven project with Java 17?

Tags: spring-boot, javafx

When I try to run a Spring Boot JavaFX project with

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I get an error "JavaFX runtime components are missing". The JDK version is 17.

I did an online search on the error message. Two solutions I find. One is to make the application modular. I don't see that is a valid solution for the Spring Boot application. And the other one is to add command line arguments for module path and modules names. The Maven command doesn't take arguments "--module-path" nor "--add-modules".

I also try to run the project with JDK only

```
 java -jar app.jar
```

Although there aren't any errors, the GUI doesn't show up.

How to resolve this issue? A good solution would be that it is easy to run without many downloading, local setup etc.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.x.x is not quite friendly  with modular applications. I have a working  **non-modular** example [here](https://github.com/ehayik/jfx-playground) Spring Boot + JFX + JDK 17 + Maven/Gradle

Comment: @eHayik Thanks for sharing your work. Your Spring + JavaFX project setup is better than mine https://github.com/vw98075/javafx-spring-boot-sample.

Comment: @eHayik I upgrade JDK to 19 of your project and I need to remove Lombok for the change. I notice a few things in your project. (1) I am unable to retrieve those properties in the application.properties with @Value{...}.

Comment: I don't know whether that is the reason you have the AppProperties class to retrieve the property data or not. Some log messages are interesting. > Task :bootRun
Jan 06, 2023 9:56:42 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup

Comment: WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @4a499116'  (java:29938): dbind-WARNING **: 21:56:43.189: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:

Comment: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files  -- it says about unsupported JavaFX configuration, dbind warning, and Dbus error. I have no ideal what they are about.

Comment: Hey, tnks for the feedback. [Lombok doesn't work with JDK 19 yet](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3264). Regarding the warning it was introduced by OpenJDK team, [It can be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67854139/javafx-warning-unsupported-javafx-configuration-classes-were-loaded-from-unna)

Comment: Regarding your issue injecting properties via @Value. It should work, if the configuration is ok, [see this commit](https://github.com/ehayik/jfx-playground/commit/c5de2fbb16d81fc0de32359f775ba1f428dd76ad).

Comment: @eHayik Thanks for your clarification. The StageRouter design is interesting. I also notice the application property file in YAML format doesn't work in all Spring Boot + JavaFX projects I have run into. Let me know if you know the reason(s)

Comment: @Rainbow you may create an [issue](https://github.com/vw98075/javafx-spring-boot-sample/issues) on my repo, adding more details in order to reproduce the issue you are facing with yml files

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 11, JavaFX was removed from the SDK. It is now in its own separate module, and if you want to use it in your application, you will need to specifically include it.

Regarding, **"to make the application modular"**:

Spring 5 and Spring Boot are not friendly with [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html). It won't really be built for modules until [Spring 6/Springboot 3](https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/09/spring-6-spring-boot-3-overhaul/) is released.

> I do try the modular approach with Spring Boot 2. However, compilation
> failed due to a known [Lombok
> error](https://leejjon.medium.com/youll-have-this-problems-when-you-add-lombok-to-a-modular-java-11-micro-service-832f55911bc5).

Regarding, **"to add command line arguments for module path and modules names. The Maven command doesn't take arguments "--module-path" nor "--add-modules"**:

You can use **non-modular** approach without `--module-path` and `--add-modules`.

[Maven configuration](https://github.com/ehayik/jfx-playground/blob/master/pom.xml) is pretty straightforward.

Firstly, Add the *JavaFX* modules you need as maven dependencies. For instance:

```xml
<properties>  
    <java.version>17</java.version>  
    <javafx.version>17.0.2</javafx.version>  
</properties>

<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>  
    <version>${javafx.version}</version>  
</dependency>  
  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>  
    <version>${javafx.version}</version>  
</dependency>
```

The project can be built and run using [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/)

**NOTE:** There is a maven plugin available for running JavaFX 11+ applications. So far, it is not required since the application will be packed and run using Spring Boot.

You may find a working example [here](https://github.com/ehayik/jfx-playground), showcasing how to bootstrap JavaFX applications within Spring Boot application.

##### How to bootstrap JavaFX application within Spring Boot application?

> The bootstrap process is heavily inspired by Mr. Awesome Josh Long’s
> [Spring Tips:
> JavaFX](https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/16/spring-tips-javafx)
> installment.

Instead of calling `SpringBootApplication.run()` use a [custom bootstrap class](https://github.com/ehayik/jfx-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/eljaiek/playground/jfx/JavaFxApplication.java) inheriting from *JavaFX* `Application`. This is needed to initialize *JavaFX* correctly.

[JavaFxApplication](https://github.com/ehayik/jfx-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/eljaiek/playground/jfx/JavaFxApplication.java) class does the heavy lifting for creating a proper *JavaFX* application with initialized [Spring  Context](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-application-context). It's responsible for:

- Set *Spring Boot* web server type to NONE.
- Programmatically create a Spring Boot context in the `Application#init()` method.
- Kick off application logic by sending a [`StageReadyEvent`](https://github.com/ehayik/jfx-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/eljaiek/playground/jfx/JavaFxApplication.java) containing the primary [Stage](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/javafx/stage.html) as payload.
- Support graceful shutdown for both *Spring* context and *JavaFX* platform.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had tried to get Josh's sample code to work before. I tried again and I got it to work this time. Your project has some differences from his project.

Answer (score -1):

Im literally searching for the same...
But I found there are some mods to do in your run-config to get this problem solved

Comment: Thanks for the info. I found that such an app needs to run as a JavaFX app, but not a Spring Boot app.  In terms of the two solutions are not user-friendly.

Comment: Please post commenst for suggestions and write self contained answer.