# JavaFX Installation

Tags: java, javafx, installation, sdk

I am new to Java and currently reading through a text and learning. I have installed the JDK in my `/opt` directory (working on Kubuntu). I have also installed openjfx in `/opt`. Since I work out the terminal, whenever I want to compile or run something involving a module from JavaFX, I use

`javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH className.java`

However, when I try the same thing with `jshell` it will not work. That is,

`jshell --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH`

What I am trying to find out is, is there any way I can install the JavaFX SDK so that it is merged with the Java SDK directory and saves me having to use the flags whenever I want to compile/run a program that requires any modules from JavaFX?

If not, can anyone tell me why the `jshell` comand above will not work as I expect it to?

Comment: The only way to do that is to use a JDK that already bundles JavaFX. I think Azul and BellSoft Liberica do so. You can't just put JavaFX into a JDK yourself (though I'm not sure trying to use JavaFX from jshell makes much sense TBH).

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: @MarkRotteveel "You can't just put JavaFX into a JDK yourself"; you essentially can do this with `jlink`. (It doesn't put JavaFX into an existing JDK, but can create a new one.)

Comment: @James_D You're right, I entirely forgot about that scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this part of your question:

> What I am trying to find out is, is there any way I can install the JavaFX SDK so that it is merged with the Java SDK directory and saves me having to use the flags whenever I want to compile/run a program that requires any modules from JavaFX?

you can use `jlink`, which generates a custom runtime image. In order to include services in the generated runtime image, use the `--bind-services` option. For reasons I don't quite understand, to include `jshell` in this, you must explicitly add the `jdk.jshell` module (simply using `--add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH` will not work). So you need something like:

```
jlink --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,jdk.jshell --bind-services --output JavaWithFX
```

to create a JDK that includes the JavaFX modules. You might need to include other JavaFX modules (e.g. `javafx.web` if you are using `WebView`, `javafx.media` if you are using `MediaPlayer`, etc.), or omit `javafx.fxml` if you are not using FXML.

Now you can just use that JDK to compile and run:

```
export JAVA_HOME=JavaWithFX
javac ClassName.java
java ClassName
```

(or possibly `export PATH=JavaWithFX/bin:$PATH` instead of the `export JAVA_HOME`, depending on how Java works on your system).

Running

```
JavaWithFX/bin/jshell
```

will give you a jshell that includes the JavaFX modules:

```
% JavaWithFX/bin/jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 20
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty

jshell> var x = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0)
x ==> IntegerProperty [value: 0]

jshell> x.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.printf("x changed from %d to %d%n", oldValue, newValue))

jshell> x.set(42)
x changed from 0 to 42

jshell>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you. I have also seen that this is now in the documentation. Further to this though, is there any downsides in now making `JavaWithFX/bin/*` our standard Java compiler and VM? Is this perhaps not a best practice? If so, what is generally recommended if you want to work with certain modules for a project -- create a custom runtime image and place it in the project root directory? Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeta-Squared The real use case for `jlink` is to build a Java runtime with just the modules needed for the application. That way, when you create a native package for application deployment, you can minimize its size. There's nothing to stop you creating a (probably large) runtime that you can use during development easily, but ultimately at deployment time you'll want to do something else.

Comment: @Zeta-Squared Generally I would strongly recommend using an IDE to manage compilation and running the application while you are developing it, and using a standard JRE (letting the IDE transparently manage the options to the compiler and execution for you). At some point, even if you use a runtime as created here, building from the terminal will become too cumbersome. (A JavaFX application will  typically need a lot of resources in addition to the compiled code: FXML files, CSS files, images, etc. You would need to copy those manually from your source to build folders.)