# Problem occuring during configuring Hibernate within JavaFX

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, javafx, java-11

i am currently working with JavaFX and i want to add a hibernate configuration.
In step 1, i need the Configuration object by Hibernate. When importing it, and correctly trying to initialize it, it gives me an error i do not fully understand. Can you help me ?

Code:

```
package com.example.databasetest;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;




public class HelloApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
    stage.setTitle("Hello!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    

    //Here is the line making the error
    Configuration config = new Configuration();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

}

When starting it, it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.doGetMessageLogger(Logger.java:2562)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2530)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.0.Final/org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.0.Final/org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.0.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:87)
    at com.example.databasetest/com.example.databasetest.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:24)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 18 more
Exception running application com.example.databasetest.HelloApplication
```

I registered hibernate in my module-info.java. I am using Java 11, it is compatible with Hibernate 5.6. It recognizes the configuration as object, but it still does throw an exception. Can you help me ?

Edit: I am aware that i need an hibernate.cfg.xml file. This is the next step to bind it into my code.

Comment: @jewelsea: "requires java.sql; " in module-info.java worked out, thanks a lot ! But i still have a question: How can one find which module to require, when there is no hint in the exception. You probably knew this out of experience, but as an IntelliJ-Beginner finding this kind of solution can be really hard.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I will consider using some of the soultion strategies.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

You need to require [java.sql](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/module-summary.html), either in your module-info or by addition of the module with VM parameters.

Or you can delete your module info and make the project non-modular as documented in getting started at openjfx.io.

Once you do any of those things, the JVM will be able to find the `java.sql.SQLException` that it is currently missing.

**Advice**

You should also use a modern java (21) and hibernate (6.3) (not necessary, but my advice).

**FAQ**

> How can one find which module to require, when there is no hint in the exception.

There is a tool called `jdeps` in the jdk you can run against a jar and it will tell you modules used with the `-—print-module-deps` option [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77235915/how-to-properly-get-the-jdk-modules-for-a-fat-javafx-jar-using-jdeps), but it is tricky to use and not foolproof.

What I do is look for the missing class (in this case java.sql.SQLException) and determine the module it is in, by finding the jar (or jdk module) it comes from and determining the module name for that.

If hibernate were properly modularized, you could require hibernate and it would automatically transitively require its dependencies, but it looks like it didn’t do that for your hibernate version.