# Create executable .JAR from JavaFX program in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm fairly new to Java and I can not for the life of me create an executable JAR file for my project in IntelliJ. The idea being that I can share that JAR file with a friend who has no programming knowledge so they can just click the JAR and run the program.

I know this is an extremely common question but I still can't get it to work. I created a new "HelloWorld" JavaFX project with a Maven build system to keep things simple while I figure things out but it doesn't work. I'm currently creating the JAR by going to Project Structure > Artifacts > + > JAR > with modules and dependencies and filling out the necessary info. I select the extract to JAR option, tried it with the Manifest being under the src folder as well as the resources folder and neither work.

If I add the VM options: `--module-path "C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-21.0.1/lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`, I can run the JAR file successfully within IntelliJ.  However when I open the JAR in explorer, it navigates to the JAR but it is labeled as a regular JAR file and is not executable. Instead, clicking on it just opens up the IntelliJ project.

JAR file in explorer:

[image: JAR file in explorer]

[image: File and Main Class Hierarchy]

Comment: It seems you've associated `*.jar` files with IntelliJ. Even if you correctly create an executable JAR, double-clicking it will open it with IntelliJ. You need to associate `*.jar` files with your installation of Java. There should be information on how to do that out there already. As for creating an executable fat/uber/shadowed JAR file for a JavaFX application, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654791/6395627) shows how to do that via Maven (the process is very similar if and when using Gradle).

Comment: For more information on different ways to package JavaFX applications, check out the "Packaging" section of the [JavaFX tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) page.

Comment: You might want to try using jarfix to fix the association. However, if you want to make sure other people won't have that problem, using jlink/jpackage could be a good idea.

Comment: Like Slaw said, you have associated .jar files with IntelliJ and not with Java. So double clicking will bot work. If it does not work either after fixing that, you can take a look into this repo: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppMavenNonModular. It contains a preconfigured full working non modular JavaFX template app, including the configurations for creating executable fat JARs with Maven.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix the *.jar association issue and run the "HelloWorld" JavaFX application both within IntelliJ and by just double-clicking the .jar file in explorer.  However, when I tried this with my more complicated project, I could only run it within IntelliJ.  If I try to run it in explorer nothing happens, just a quick flash of the buffer wheel and that's it.  I'm not sure if it's worth noting but when I run both project .jars in IntelliJ, I get the red error text in the terminal: "WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @7ea36e97'".

Comment: I'm not sure if the warning is a result of IntelliJ not recognizing the file type of the .dll files from the javafx sdk bin folder when I'm adding them to the .jar.  From the videos I've seen, .dll should be a recognized file type but for some reason these particular files are not recognized but still seem to perform their job.

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67854139/6395627) to understand the warning. Since your chosen deployment strategy is an executable JAR file that includes JavaFX, you'll just have to ignore the warning. Though note that this approach means your main class **cannot** be a subclass of `javafx.application.Application`; you need a separate "launcher class" to be the main class. As for figuring out what's wrong with your "more complicated project", try launching the JAR from the terminal and see what errors are emitted.

Comment: See also https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help! I was able to find the source of the error and fix it so the jar runs fine on my computer.  I was also able to package it with launch4j as that seemed a bit simpler than jpackage or jlink.

Comment: However, the error that I was running into was a matter of not being able to find the .txt file that I referenced in the Main.java application.  When I referenced the file I used the file path to find and access the file so when I moved the jar to a different computer to test everything it could no longer find the file.  I keep this file under the project src folder so it can travel with the project and use it to save work but the path will still change if I share it and I will run into issues.  Is there a way I can reference the file and the changing pathway won't be an issue?

Comment: I added a picture to show the hierarchy, I'm just not sure how to reference the file when the absolute path is always changing.